# Excel Date field value differs from c# dateTime by 1 day while reading excel file with EEPlus

Tags: c#, excel, date, xlsx

I have a problem with getting correct date field value from excel (.xlsx) file with EEPlus library.

The particular problem is that in excel i have e.g. 1900.01.04, but in C# I get 1900.01.03.

I had an idea, that when I read date value from excel it (EEPlus) converts it to utc and I should convert it to local time zone, but as time values of date object are nil it's probably not the case.

```
var date = (DateTime) Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing it to if it changes anything:

var date = Worksheet.Cells[row, column].GetValue<DateTime>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the EEPlus date differs from the Excel date then it is probably a bug in EEPlus.

It is likely that it is accounting for the [infamous Excel 1900 leap year bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214326) but only for dates after February 29(!!) 1900.

Comment: EEPlus does not have the bug, Excel does. - dates that result in a day before March 1st,1900 will either be invalid (Feb 29th 1900) or one day out, because of the invalid date due to the bug you mentioned