# Convert Java date to Excel date results in one more day than actual, before March 1, 1900

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I am using POI to export some data into an Excel file. I have some code to insert some date into Excel sheet cell as date (rather than text). I works fine for dates after 01/03/1900. However for dates before that, it results a dates one more day than actual day.

```
    //SOME CODE 
    final HSSFDataFormat dateFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();
    final HSSFCellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    dateStyle.setDataFormat(dateFormat.getFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"));
    dataCell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);

    final Date date = DateUtil.parseDate(dataCellValue);
    dataCell.setCellValue(HSSFDateUtil.getExcelDate(date));
```

I am using POI VERSION: 3.0-alpha2-20060616

Just wonder why it is and does building a function or do updates fix the issue?

Comment: Almost certainly another manifestation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915228/excel-date-field-value-differs-from-c-sharp-datetime-by-1-day-while-reading-exce/19915379#19915379

Comment: thanks, Jon. That's really helpful. Does POI provide a fix in the later version? or developers need to sort it out by them self?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Apache POI that is almost 10 years old? (Hint - the release date is in the file!). Why not upgrade to something from this decade?

Comment: @Gagravarr,thank you for your response. I am new to POI, and seems the company used this for a long time. I have also checked the release after 2006, seems they did not clearly status a bug or fix for this problem.

Comment: You are using a 10 year old alpha version! Pretty much anything is likely to be better than that...